# To increase site loading speed what should we aim at: decreasing http requests / saving overall page size?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, http, minify

(My site has 110Kb in images, one rotator, 2 google fonts)

My Wordpress site made 30 http requests, took 7 seconds to load, overall page size 220Kb. By changing various plugins, I managed to bring down the requests to 22, 6.1 seconds, page size bloated to 320Kb (2 google fonts classified as CSS images, by websiteoptimisation.com)

Because minifying & combining .js no doubt, reduces filesize, but then it sits in the middle blocking everything.

I tried various script compressors, but with similar results. Still Yslow & PageSpeed shout on minified files (this file could have been compressed by 40%...)

My question is what should we aim at? reduce http requests/minify & combine files/prevent bloating overall page size?

Comment: You have to decide whether you want to optimize page load speed, or "time to first content".  These two are usually conflicting with each other.  In general, reduce the number of requests definitely works, and it is definitely worth merging all your JS into one file and then minifying it.  100KB in images does not sound too much, especially if you set the correct caching headers so that your visitors do not need to load them again.

Comment: However, you should profile your app.  It doesn't look like downloading may be the culprit for your site spending 6 seconds to load.  320KB is not a lot to go over the wire.  What kind of speed do you see after you've loaded your browser's cache?

Answer (score 0):

In principal, it depends on many factors (such as- if your users have low bandwidth, it might be preferable to keep the page size to a minimum.)
In my opinion, however, generally- the number of http requests is far more important than page size.
keep in mind that modern browsers can cache static content (.js files, .css etc.), so the page size might reduce over time.
If you can supply some more info on the requests your page generates, perhaps we can give you more specific advice.